# Android GPS OnLocationChange Crash

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

I continue to get this error and crash, whenever I try to run my android application. It is supposed to retrieve the current gps location and update a textview called log on the data activity.

> 07-02 09:28:40.978 27682-27682/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416aeba8)
>   07-02 09:28:40.978 27682-27682/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.novakinc.novak, PID: 27682
>                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at com.novakinc.novak.MainActivity$1.onLocationChanged(MainActivity.java:52)
>                                                          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
>                                                          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
>                                                          at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.novakinc.novak">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".help" />
    <activity android:name=".about" />
    <activity android:name=".data"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.novakinc.novak;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            data.log.append("\n " + location.getLongitude() + " " +     location.getLatitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED   && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=   PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]  {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    ,10);
        }
        return;
    }
    // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);


}


//---------------------------------------Menu---------------------------------------------------

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, about.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, help.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.data:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, data.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//---------------------------------------End Menu-----------------------------------------------

}
```

data.java :

```
package com.novakinc.novak;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class data extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static TextView log;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
        log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is data.log a static variable in the data activity ? you would need to assign a reference to it before appending something to it

Comment: so you are getting an NPE because the text view is not initialized the first time. But why do you want to append to a text view in activity that is not visisble?

Comment: because you can got to the data activity and view a log.

Comment: And the text view does have a initial value. It defaults as "New Text"

Comment: You can take a String in MainActivity save whatever you want to in the on locationchanged method and while starting the data activity pass that string in put extra to the data activity and when get that string in the on create method of data activity and set it in the textview

Answer (score -1):

You are getting a Nullpointer Exception, because in LocationListener you are getting a value from Location which is null. Always check (if) nulls.

Comment: Can you create a example.